# Deleting a row in the collection with reference

Tags: java, mongodb, jpa

I have two documents in mongodb. One of them has reference to other document. If I remove Item, reference in Order there is still a non-existent object.

```
@Document(collection = "orders")
public class Order {
    @Id 
    @GeneratedValue()
    String id;

    @DBRef
    List<Item> items;

    //getters and setters
}

@Document(collection = "items")
public class Item {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue()
    String id;

    long productId;

    //getters and setters
}

@Autowired
ItemRepository itemRepo;

Item item = itemRepo.findOne(itemId);
itemRepo.delete(item);
```

How delete it with reference in list?

Comment: I assume you are talking about the Java object model you have in your code rather than the documents that exist within the MongoDB database? As in you're asking how to delete an item and then automagically have that item disappear from the items list in your Order instances?

Comment: Of course. I have delete an item and then automatically have that item disappear from the items list in my Order instance.